# Angular Material Accordion ngFor with inner component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

We currently have the problem that we are using a component inside a mat-accordion.

The code is as follows

`<mat-accordion>
    <app-customer-item *ngFor="let customerResult of searchResult.foundCustomers"
        (emitter)="sendNotification($event)" 
        (goToCustomer)="goToCustomer($event)"
        [customer]="customerResult" [searchTerm]="searchCriteria?.searchTerm"
        [tabName]="Customers">
    </app-customer-item>
</mat-accordion>`

However this will get rendered including the `<app-customer-item>` tag and thus leading to incorrect html and inproper display of the accordion.

The `app-customer-item` has a `mat-expansion-panel` at its root.

Then we found that we can use an attribute selector as described here: https://paulsalaets.com/posts/angular-component-and-child-selectors

When we do that, we get the following justifiable error message:

> ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: More than one component matched on this element. Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element. Conflicting components: MatExpansionPanel,CustomerItemComponent ("                                               [ERROR ->]                                [ERROR ->]http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:39013:17 ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js/TemplateParser.prototype.parse@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56897:19 ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype._parseTemplate@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62443:16 ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype._compileTemplate@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62430:18 ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62373:56 ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62373:9 ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62283:13 then@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:39004:77 ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62282:16 ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype.compileModuleAsync@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62242:32 ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js/CompilerImpl.prototype.compileModuleAsync@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:144950:16 ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/SystemJsNgModuleLoader.prototype.loadAndCompile/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:80917:44 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2733:17 onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:79900:24 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2732:17 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2483:24 scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3217:29 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2766:17 onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:79891:24 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2765:17 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2533:28 drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2940:25 ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2845:21 invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3885:9 globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3911:17 " resolvePromise11Angular core.js:14597

Obviously the `*ngFor` will create multiple elements that will match. But we want multiple component elements inside.

Here is the final code:

`<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel app-customer-item *ngFor="let customerResult of searchResult.foundCustomers"
        (emitter)="sendNotification($event)" 
        (goToCustomer)="goToCustomer($event)"
        [customer]="customerResult" [searchTerm]="searchCriteria?.searchTerm"
        [tabName]="Customers">
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>`

Any suggestions on how to fix that? Thank you!

Comment: I guess the error is more about your selector : `mat-expansion-panel[app-customer-item]` (or `[app-customer-item]`) matches two components : yours, and the material one. This isn't a solution that is suited to your case. I think it would be easier to just get the expansion panel out of your custom component.

Comment: I don't get what the result should look like.

Comment: @JosefKatič you might want to take a look at https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview - it shows how the html structure has to be. however, when I want to put a component inside the mat-accordion, the components parent html tag will also be inside the dom. thus why we are using the selector.

Comment: What's the `selector` in `customer-item.component.ts`?

Comment: @JosefKatič it is 'mat-expansion-panel[customer-item-component]'

Comment: Then you are defining twice `mat-expansion-panel`.